# How can I reply to S/MIME signed messaged in Web Outlook (outlook.office.com) when using Firefox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smime

Whenever I get an S/MIME signed message I have no problems reading it but I can not reply to it. Clicking on the Reply button does nothing.
I understand that I can not sign the reply message but I do not want to sign it, I want a normal reply.
Is there a way to achieve this?

I am using Web Outlook (new version) and Firefox browser.

Comment: This sounds like a blocked popup window or similar. Have you checked that your Firefox allows popups on outlook.office.com? Any active ad blockers? You should be able to answer signed messages, but maybe Outlook tries to display a warning popup first.

Comment: There is no blocked popup and I've ad-blocker was disabled. There is actually a javascript error when I click on 'Reply' button:

TypeError: 
e is null

AAMkADU1NDU2MmJkLWFiMzEtNDBhZC1iNGMwLWRjNTM0ZGMxM2RhNgBGAAAAAADewJ9ICDYlQaLCkXV4NDupBwACdjpSyWEtQKmE1UQ8l9CvAAAAAAFVAAACdjpSyWEtQKmE1UQ8l9CvAAF7Fk0KAAA=:350:2870

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the outlook javascript. Does it work in other browsers?